# Subgroup generated by a maximal subgroup and a conjugate of itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$ and $g\in G$ not in $M$. Then $\langle M, gMg^{-1}\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $M$, so by the maximality of $M$, we must have $\langle M, gMg^{-1}\rangle = M$ or $\langle M, gMg^{-1}\rangle = G$. Can $\langle M, gMg^{-1}\rangle = M$ if $g\notin M$?

Comment: $M$ can be normal...

Comment: Okay thanks. This was a proof from a textbook in showing that any maximal subgroup is pronormal. No mention of M being normal was made. They just considered the case where $\langle M, gMg^{-1} \rangle = G$. I'm not sure why

Comment: If $\langle M, g^{-1}Mg \rangle = M$, then it follows that $g^{-1}Mg \subseteq M$, hence $M \subseteq gMg^{-1}$ and by the maximality of $M$ this gives $M=g^{-1}Mg$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $M$ is not normal. Then $N_G(M)=M$. If $\langle M, g^{-1}Mg \rangle = M$, then it follows that $g^{-1}Mg \subseteq M$, hence $M \subseteq gMg^{-1}$ and by the maximality of $M$ this gives $M=g^{-1}Mg$. Hence $g \in N_G(M)$, that is $g \in M$.